# Detect cause of timeout in Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I am writing an bot in C# with the Microsoft Bot Framework which is hosted as Azure web app and calls either some Azure API or a Google Cloud API.

Locally everything works fine but when deployed to Azure the Call to the Google Cloud API never returns and my the Microsoft Bot Frameworks gives me an timeout error message.

I searched through the Azure portal in order to find some more detailed information why this outgoing call might not return correctly but so far I found nothing useful. I can't see any error on the diagnostics sites and remote debugging just never return from the API calls.

Does anybody know if I can enable some more debug/error information for this problem?

---

Edit after comments:

@Mark C.: I am able to call and get a result form the Google Service (text sentiment) when I run the app locally, so the Google Cloud API should be fine.

@Hackerman: The mapping is know to me. I try to compare some Services between Azure and Google, in this case the text sentiment API. I enabled stream logging, but there are no errors/warnings printed out.

@Bruce MSFT: The method is like this. Both azure and google paths work locally. Only the Azure path works when deployed to Azure web apps. When I remote debug the Azure Web App I can step to "client.AnalyzeSentimentAsync" and when I press next the next line is never reached. Instead after 10 (?) minutes I get an exception from mscorlib: "{"Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail=\"Deadline Exceeded\")"}"

```
public async Task<int> DetectSentiment(string text, bool useAzure = false)
{
    if (useAzure)
    {
        var request = new SentimentRequest();
        request.Documents.Add(new AzureDocument
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Text = text
        });

        var client = new SentimentClient(_key);
        var response = await client.GetSentimentAsync(request);
        return Convert.ToInt32(response.Documents[0].Score * 100);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            var client = LanguageServiceClient.Create();
            var response = await client.AnalyzeSentimentAsync(new GoogleDocument
            {
                Content = text,
                Type = GoogleDocument.Types.Type.PlainText
            });

            return Convert.ToInt32((response.DocumentSentiment.Score + 1) * 50);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a timeout, have you made sure that you can call the Google Cloud API from something other than your app?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Comment: Or maybe you need to map something: https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/map-azure-google-cloud-platform

Comment: Could you provide some key code about calling to the Google Cloud API, in order to isolate this issue?